# Method that generates two random numbers within a changeable range

Tags: java, random

For my assignment, I need to create a method of a random math generator in which you can practice addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.

I need to create a method in which the range is different based on what operation you are doing.. For example

**1. Addition problems**

- Both operands should be random numbers in the range, 1 to 500, inclusive

**2. Subtraction problems**

- Both operands should be random numbers in the range, 1 to 999, inclusive
- But the second operand, (the number being subtracted from the top number) should be less than or equal to the first operand

**3. Multiplication problems**

- The first operand (top number) must be in the range of 1 to 100, inclusive.
- The second operand (bottom number) must be in the range of 1 to 9, inclusive.

**4. Division problems**

- The range for the divisor (operand 2) must be from 1 to 9, inclusive
- The dividend (operand 1) must have a value such that the resulting quotient is always in the range of 1 to 50, inclusive

Then after that, I would do an if else statement that looks similar to this:

```
 correctAnswer = firstRandomNumber + secondRandomNumber
 if (userInput = correctAnswer) 
    { 
      system.out.println ("Correct!");
     } else {
        system.out.println ("Wrong!");
    }
```

How would I go on about doing this?

Comment: [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)

Answer (score -1):

This should be a good place to start:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class RandomNumberRange {

    private int random(int min, int max) {
        int number = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return number;
    }

    public int[] numberforOperation(String operation) {
        if (operation.equals("addition")) {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 500;
            int[] operands = {random(min, max), random(min, max)};
            return operands;
        }
        if (operation.equals("subtraction") {
            int min = 1;
            int max =999;
            int minuend = random(min, max);
            int subtrahend = random(min, minuend);
        }

        /**** etc. *** etc.***/

        else (return null);
    }    
}
```

Comment: `if (operation == "addition") ` is not a proper way to compare Strings - use `if (Objects.equals(operation, "addition"))` or `if (operation.equals("addition"))` if `operation` can't be `null`.

Comment: Sadly we are not allowed to use arrays since that was not covered at the time the assignment was handed out.

Comment: Erwin - quite correct about using equals methods. Thanks - I edited. Regarding the null it would push validation of "operation" at the client class. Didn't want to obscure code with validation code or do what I would normally do which is to use enum.

Comment: malsafoo - You have other choices. I picked an array because it was quick an dirty and just wanted to show the concept without getting complicated. You can create a class to hold your operands. That's way more elegant if your are allowed to do that. Worse case scenario, create two methods. One for operand1 and one for operand2. It's ugly and cumbersome but it will work.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot the most obvious work around. Just put the two methods in the same class as as your other code and create class (not method) variables for operand 1 and operand 2. It not good practice, but it's simple and it works.

Comment: Last suggestion also has the benefit that the "numberForOperation" method will not have a return value -- so it avoids completely the issue of having to return a void if the input is something other than one of the the four operations.

Comment: @LucTalbot please use the @ mention feature, otherwise people will not see your comment in their comment inbox